# Is it possible to create a JS variable using the data that is available in the HTTP Response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some data in my browser's network HTTP response that i would like to use to create JS variables. Is this possible?

```
{
 "stepId" : "step1",
"formInfo" : {
"schema" : {
  "title" : "intro"
    }
  }
},
```

I have these information in my http response, how can i create a JS variable for "stepId"?

Thanks

Comment: If the response is in JSON format, you need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to a JS object/array. Then you can use ordinary object or array syntax to get parts of it.

Comment: I also think that if you're using jQuery to do this that it will automatically parse and return a JSON object in your `complete/then()` function.

Comment: @Barmar, yes the response is in JSON, do you have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you get that specific JSON object as response from, for example an `ajax` `get` method (HTTP GET), you may get your variable `stepId` by the following

```
$.get("demo_test.php", function(data, status){
    var stepId = JSON.parse(data)["stepId"];
});
```